# arreglo compact php en Js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, array, blade

Estoy intentando cargar un chart.js. Envié los datos mediante un `compact` el problema es que no logro incluirlo dentro de mi JS.

```
var chart = new Chart(miCanvas,{
type:"line",
data:{
        labels  : [@foreach ($DatosDeGrafica as $especialidad )
                       {{ $especialidad->especialidad }}
                   @endforeach
                  ],
```

Intente hacerlo con el `foreach` de blade, pero JS simplemente no lo reconoce. Es como que dentro de JS Blade no funciona. El JS esta dentro del mismo archivo Blade, no es un archivo externo. Alguna idea?

Este es el arreglo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con ````{!! json_encode($especialidad->especialidad) !!}```` (Suponiendo que ````$especialidad->especialidad```` es tu arreglo completo)

Comment: No se si es la falta de sueño o los 5 redbull, pero, si tengo un foreach (JS), como hago que el dato se imprima ahi mismo. Lo que seria un 'echo' en php? Y si, lo que dijiste me ayudo. Ahora necesito imprimir la variable luego de realizar el foreach, y no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar contenido desde php a js mediante blade necesitas hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
{!! json_encode($especialidad->especialidad) !!}
```

Nos apoyamos de `json_encode()` que nos permitirá dejar el contenido de la variable en un string JSON valido para javascript. La salida anterior la "renderizamos" con `{!! !!}` porque  `{{ }}` hace uso por defecto de la función [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php).

**RECOMENDACIÓN SUBJETIVA**

En la practica no me gusta mezclar operaciones de javascript con blade, en su lugar al principio del archivo defino una variable que contendrá mi objeto y al estar definida de las primeras, tendrá el contenido disponible para el resto del código.

Una vez que ha sucedido lo anterior, me olvido de blade y sigo trabajando solo con js, esto me permite modificar en tiempo de ejecución (en javascript) el contenido que pase originalmente desde blade.

Ej:

```
//EJEMPLO REFERENCIAL

// Acá inicializo todas mis variables de blade en js
var my_php_object = {!! json_encode($especialidad->especialidad) !!}


// MI CODIGO 
// acá ya puedo usar las variables de blade como js tradicional
var chart = new Chart(miCanvas,{
type:"line",
data: my_php_object


// OBSERVACIÓN
// Ahora al trabajar directamente con js podrías modificar parte o el total de tu objeto y los cambios se mantendrán en la instancia de ejecución.
my_php_object  = []
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Seguiré tu consejo para tener una mejor organización en mi código. Y si, el `json_encode( )` funcionó genial.